# Adding a Textbox and storing the data from it in a .csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, textbox

Is there a possibility of adding a textbox in a webpage and the data entered in it can be stored in a .csv file ? I know that whatever we enter in a textbox is usually stored in the browser.

Comment: Any Language like PHP or C# else just using javascript/jquery only ?

Comment: You need to use some server side language like `php, c# or anyother`

Comment: krish - using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Not possible to create a file using pure javascript, because javscript runs on a web browser and the browser does not have enough permission yet.

There is some possibility in chrome browser but **not supports** on other browser

```
function exportToCsv() {
            var myCsv = "Col1,Col2,Col3\nval1,val2,val3";

            window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myCsv));
        }

        var button = document.getElementById('b');
        button.addEventListener('click', exportToCsv);
```

Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/Ln6GP/

you will asked to download the file when you click the button.

Also seen a project on github check this too http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/